# Notificação de edição de postagens

Tags: suporte, edições-sugeridas, notificações

Quando há edições que necessitam de aprovações em alguma pergunta/resposta que a gente criou, recebemos uma notificação de que há/houve uma edição no conteúdo.  Porém, parece que o mesmo não ocorre quando é feita uma edição que não necessita de aprovação.

Por que a notificação não ocorre para ambos os casos?

**Edit:** O @Bacco sugeriu que isso pode ser consequência de o usuário que editou, ter medalha de ouro em uma das tags da pergunta/resposta que foi editada, isso pode influir nas notificações?

<sub>*Obs.: a pergunta é apenas a título de curiosidade mesmo, não é uma sugestão de funcionalidade.*</sub>

Comment: Eu achava que qualquer edição de terceiros num post nosso gerava uma notificação... vou ver se localizo um post seu pra testar... (edit, fiz uma)

Comment: @brasofilo recebi a notificação, mas conversando no chat, o Bacco me disse que pode ser que quem editou tenha medalha de ouro, o bigown mesmo já editou alguns posts e não recebi notificação. Faz até sentido se a pessoa tem medalha mas gostaria de saber se é isso mesmo.

Comment: editei uma pergunta... chegaram a testar a teoria da tag?

Comment: @brasofilo ainda não, vou ver se encontro alguém com a tal medalha de ouro em alguma tag de pergunta que eu fiz pra testar.