# Notificação de resposta editada?

Tags: suporte, edição

Recentemente fiz uma resposta em que eu realmente tinha cometido alguns erros no texto. Felizmente foi erro de redação, os editores perceberam que minha intenção era ter escrito outras coisas.

> A propósito, obrigado ao Articuno e ao Victor Stafusa por me corrigirem

Então eu recebi uma notificação de "reposta editada:

[image: notificação de resposta editada]

Mas não lembro de em algum momento ter recebido esse tipo de notificação quando um usuário de alta reputação realiza as edições.

Quando que essas notificações são enviadas? Por que elas são enviadas?

Comment: Comigo acontece de vez em quando, mas é algo incomum. Nunca me perguntei se era *sempre* que algo meu era editado por outrem ou se só *às vezes* (inclusive recebi esses dias uma em que você editou, e a sua edição era correta).

Comment: Relacionada: [Notificação de edição de postagens](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4963/28595)

Comment: Acho que minha resposta responde a essa pergunta, mas da uma olhada lá pra ver se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Quando a conjunção dos planetas forem ideais :)

Comment: Aliás, duplicata exata. Como que faz para marcar?